# Is it possible to create a dynamic device group membership based on the existence of a file on the local drive within Azure?

Tags: azure, dynamic, membership, group

Looking for a way to create a dynamic device group membership based on a single file on the local drive in Azure. Tried utilizing Powershell within the rule syntax section, but it appears to only accept code based on the rule builder. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To create dynamic group for device we need ***Azure AD Premium*** . So that can Create an expression to add users or devices to user groups or device groups automatically.

**NOTE:-**

***BASED ON*** [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENT***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership):-

> - *You can establish a dynamic group for either devices or users, but you can't create a rule that includes both*.
> - *You can't make a device group based on the properties of the device owners. Only device attributes can be referenced in device membership
>   rules.*

For more information please refer the *aforementioned* *MS DOC* and below link:

**MICROSOFT DOCUMENT**|[***Create or update a dynamic group in Azure Active Directory***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-create-rule)  & [***Add groups to organize users and devices***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/groups-add)